# XSLT to Count Co-occurrences of Specific Child Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to count the number of co-occurrences of particular people inside event records in an xml document.  My source document is made up of event elements that contain prose in p elements and bibliographic records in bibl elements, both of which contain references to people.  I would like to be able to count how often two people show up together in events in the entire document.  I've been using XSLT 2.0, but can switch to 3.0.

(how, for example can I get the answer 3 for the number of times that Nancy Drew and Dick Tracy are in events together below? or 1 for Dick Tracy and Sam Spade?)

```
<listEvent>
        <event xml:id="e1">
           <p>pretium eget erat eu cursus. Duis pulvinar lectus sed quam vehicula tincidunt in
              vel nunc. Cras convallis elementum diam. Sed nec viverra magna. Then <name
                 SameAs="detectives.xml#ND">Nancy Drew</name> solved the case. A consequat
              tortor molestie ut. Praesent lobortis ipsum sit amet bibendum consequat. </p>

           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#DT">Tracy, Dick</name>. The Mysterious Case of the
              Orange Fish. Penguin Publishing. </bibl>
           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#SH">Holmes, Sherlock</name>. The Case of the Blue
              Carbuncle Penguin Publishing. </bibl>

        </event>
        <event xml:id="e2">
           <p> facilisis turpis eu, gravida enim. Mauris adipiscing magna consequat dolor
              auctor, sit amet tincidunt felis auctor. <name SameAs="detectives.xml#ND">Nancy
                 Drew</name> and <name SameAs="detectives.xml#DT">Dick Tracy</name> went into
              business together. Aliquam pharetra semper erat, at viverra tellus vestibulum
              quis. Sed facilisis convallis justo, suscipit fermentum lorem egestas nec.
              Phasellus in aliquam eros, vitae fringilla augue </p>

           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#TH">Hardy, Tom</name>. Growing Up Is Hard to Do:
              The Story of a Boy Detective. Knopf Press. </bibl>
           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#SH">Holmes, Sherlock</name>. The Case of the Blue
              Carbuncle. Penguin Publishing. </bibl>
           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#SH">Holmes, Sherlock</name>. The Hound of the
              Baskervilles. Arsenal Press. </bibl>

        </event>
        <event xml:id="e3">
           <p> Curabitur dapibus eu ligula sed elementum. Curabitur sit amet nisi dictum. <name
                 SameAs="detectives.xml#SS">Sam Spade</name> was the only detective in town.
              Donec cursus diam sem, astor. </p>

           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#TH">Hardy, Tom</name>. Growing Up Is Hard to Do:
              The Story of a Boy Detective. Knopf Press. </bibl>
           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#SS">Spade, Sam</name>. My Friends' Business
              Ventures. Knopf Press. </bibl>
           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#DN">Drew, Nancy</name>. Blonde and Curious.
              Arsenal Press.</bibl>

        </event>
        <event xml:id="e4">
           <p> Duis pulvinar lectus sed quam vehicula tincidunt in vel nunc. <name
                 SameAs="detectives.xml#ND">Nancy Drew</name> and <name
                 SameAs="detectives.xml#DT">Dick Tracy</name> made 110% profit that year. Cras
              convallis elementum diam. Sed nec viverra magna. A consequat tortor molestie ut.
              Praesent lobortis ipsum sit amet bibendum consequat. </p>

           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#SS">Spade, Sam</name>. My Friends' Business
              Ventures. Knopf Press. </bibl>
           <bibl><name SameAs="detectives.xml#MH">Holmes, Mycroft</name>. Sons and Brothers.
              Knopf Press. </bibl>
        </event>
     </listEvent>
```

@michael.hor257k I like your thinking.  I am hoping to get output that looks like this:

```
<gexf> <graph><nodes count="77">
<node id="1.0" label="Sam Spade"/>
<node id="2.0" label="Dick Tracy"/>
<node id="3.0" label="Nancy Drew"/>
…
</nodes>

<edges count="254">
<edge id="1" source="1.0" target="2.0" weight="1.0"/>
<edge id="2" source="1.0" target="3.0" weight="2.0"/>
<edge id="3" source="2.0" target="3.0" weight="3.0"/>
…
</edges>
</graph>
</gexf>
```

... where the @weight value is what I am having trouble computing.

I have managed to assign each person a node @id.  The node @ids then make up the @source and @target values (the first is Sam Spade and Dick Tracy, the second Sam Spade and Nancy Drew), and @weight should be the number of times they show up together in a doc (I have --annoyingly perhaps-- simplified my example. In my actual source doc there are a bunch of other attributes and values in each element, including a @n for each person's name, so using a value-of select to populate the @ids, @sources, and @target was a snap).

@tim , not to worry, the the @SameAs points to an authority list, so that no matter how an individual's name is spelled in the text (i.e., Lucy, Miss Graham, and Mrs. L. Foster could all be names in the text for the same woman, as girl, before she married and after, or reversed as is in the case in a bibliographic entry) it can be resolved into a single person.

Comment: Do you mean you want to examine every possible combination of two names? Perhaps you should post an example of what the output should look like, code-wise.

Comment: You've got a "Nancy Drew" and a "Drew, Nancy" in your XML. Would you expect these would be treated as different names? (The @SameAs attribute differs for them too).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I like your thinking.  The output should look like this: `<gexf>
<graph><nodes count="77">
<node id="1.0" label="Sam Spade"/>
<node id="2.0" label="Dick Tracy"/>
<node id="3.0" label="Nancy Drew"/>
…
</node>

<edges count="254">
<edge id="1" source="1.0" target="2.0" weight="1.0"/>
<edge id="2" source="1.0" target="3.0" weight="2.0"/>
<edge id="3" source="2.0" target="3.0" weight="3.0"/>
…
</edges>
</graph>
/gefx>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not to worry, the the @SameAs points to an authority list

Well, the thing that is an XSLT lives by what's in the XML source document - so the required counts here will be made **before** the different @SameAs values are resolved.

> In my actual source doc there are a bunch of other attributes and
>   values in each element, including a @n for each person's name

Okay, so since we don't have that, I have used the @SameAs attribute as if it were a distinct id. The following is actually an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, beefed up by the EXSLT set:distinct() function. This is just a sketch with some of the scaffolding left in, so we can see if this is headed in the right direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="eventByID" match="event" use=".//name/@SameAs" />

<xsl:variable name="distinct_nodes" select="set:distinct(/listEvent/event//name/@SameAs)" />
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<graph>
    <nodes>
        <xsl:for-each select="$distinct_nodes">
            <node id="{.}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
        <xsl:for-each select="$distinct_nodes[not(position()=last())]">
            <xsl:variable name="source" select="." />
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$distinct_nodes[position()>$pos]">
                    <xsl:variable name="target" select="." />
                    <xsl:variable name="common_events" select="key('eventByID', $source)[@xml:id=key('eventByID', $target)/@xml:id]" />
                    <xsl:if test="$common_events">
                        <edge source="{$source}" target="{$target}" weight="{count($common_events)}">
                        <!-- use this for test purposes -->
                            <!-- 
                            <xsl:for-each select="$common_events">
                                <event id="{@xml:id}"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                             -->
                        </edge>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </edges>
</graph>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example XML, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<graph>
   <nodes>
      <node id="detectives.xml#ND"/>
      <node id="detectives.xml#DT"/>
      <node id="detectives.xml#SH"/>
      <node id="detectives.xml#TH"/>
      <node id="detectives.xml#SS"/>
      <node id="detectives.xml#DN"/>
      <node id="detectives.xml#MH"/>
   </nodes>
   <edges>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#ND" target="detectives.xml#DT" weight="3"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#ND" target="detectives.xml#SH" weight="2"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#ND" target="detectives.xml#TH" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#ND" target="detectives.xml#SS" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#ND" target="detectives.xml#MH" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#DT" target="detectives.xml#SH" weight="2"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#DT" target="detectives.xml#TH" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#DT" target="detectives.xml#SS" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#DT" target="detectives.xml#MH" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#SH" target="detectives.xml#TH" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#TH" target="detectives.xml#SS" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#TH" target="detectives.xml#DN" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#SS" target="detectives.xml#DN" weight="1"/>
      <edge source="detectives.xml#SS" target="detectives.xml#MH" weight="1"/>
   </edges>
</graph>
```

Comment: I've never tried EXSLT before. @michael.hor257k your result is *exactly* what I am looking for, but I when I try the sheet I am getting a fatal error from Saxon-EE 9.5.1.3
"XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://exslt.org/sets}distinct()", even though the sets namespace looks perfect.  I've tried Saxon 6.5.5 and Xalan, which will complete the transformation but return empty node and graph elements.  Am I diagnosing this correctly? Am I using the wrong processors?

Comment: @CLKC It works fine in both [Saxon 6.5.5](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Ya) and [Xalan 2.7.1](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Ya/1). In XSLT 2.0, I suppose you have to write your own: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-distinct-nodes-stable

Comment: Something like [this](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Ya/2), I guess; there are likely some simplifications that can be made if using a XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: thank you for the XSLT 2.0.  I have found my mistake--thank you so much for the stylesheets. I am too much of a noob to be allowed to vote up answers, but I will find someone who can, because yours are spot on.